# Spring webflux | keep connection alive indefinitely

Tags: netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty, spring-webclient

We need to keepalive the connection open indefinitely and reconnect in case the response from server is not found or any error.

We are thinking of using IdleStateHandler and HeartbeatHandler to achieve the same but have difficulty in writing the code. Can someone help us with pseudo code or some help to achieve the same. This is what we have so far.

```
        ConnectionProvider elasticPool = ConnectionProvider.elastic("productDef-pool");
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
                .create(elasticPool)
                .keepAlive(true)
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient ->
                        tcpClient.doOnConnected(connection -> {
                            if (connection.channel().pipeline().get("write_timeout") == null)
                                connection
                                        .channel()
                                        .pipeline()
                                        .addFirst("write_timeout", new WriteTimeoutHandler(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
                            if (connection.channel().pipeline().get("read_timeout") == null)
                                connection
                                        .channel()
                                        .pipeline()
                                        .addFirst("read_timeout", new ReadTimeoutHandler(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
                        }))
                .wiretap(true);

        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .defaultHeader("Authorization", "1")
                .defaultHeader("Trace_Id", "3")
                .defaultHeader("Span_Id", "4")
                .defaultHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .filter(hmacHeaderExchangeFilter)
                .baseUrl("https://productdef-dev.test.com")
                .build();
```

Comment: `but have difficulty in writing the code` what is difficult, are you getting an error, exception, what unexpected behaviour, logs, you only say you have a problem,, but not what the problem actually is.

Comment: We are not sure how to add the idlestatehandler and heartbeathandler. We looked on internet to see if anyone has used these handlers but couldn't find any pseudo code. How do we handle if the destination server restarts and we need to reopen the connection ?